# apache solr and searching simple text file (not csv)

Tags: solr, full-text-search

First day with Solr and seems its accepts a josn document system as items. I have a flat text file (26meg) and for the first stage, I just want to do a efficient full text search with regex on it.
I cannot find a good steps on importing this simple 26M file into the index so that searching can start.

Answer (score 1):

Solr is not designed for regex search. It's designed for keyword search with a lot of functionality to be smart about it. Similar how you would not search in Google with regex.

The bigger problem in your question is that you mention **one** file repeatedly. Solr is designed to index many **documents** and then return those **documents** that match the query.

What would a document be in your **one file**? If it's just one document, what's the point of indexing and searching it? It's easier to think about it backwards: when you search with your keywords, what do you get back? It should be N items of X. So, the X is normally the unit/document in Solr and you need to decide how your file maps to that.

Which should be a separate - more specific - question.

Comment: Getting the idea now. Thanks. If I search "A B C" i'm looking to get results on how many times they appear, sorted based on how close they appear, same sentence, neighbor sentence, etc. Its natural language so they wont ever be exact match. Thats my problem, i have to work on 1 file at a time. You think sphinx is better at this?

Comment: All of the search engines I know off are based on the same underlying principles. So, you really need to develop your use-case more. You still haven't defined what "match/document" looks like. It sounded like a sentence, but then you seem to want to match cross-sentence too. If your content is non-chunkable, maybe search engine is not the right approach for you and you are just looking for more n-grams and Finite State Machines from NLP domain. I would recommend doing Search Engine tutorials while keeping your requirements in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index arbitrary JSON files. They'll have to be formatted in the way Solr expects, in practice structured as a list of documents to index.

```
[
 {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"},
 {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"}
]
```

See [The JSON Update Format](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON). This format is also reflected in your schema.xml, where the definition of each field present in your JSON document structure should be added (and proper types/analyzers/filters/tokenizers set up).

Comment: I just have a flat text file, its not a csv, just lot of readable text. and its 50MB in size.

Comment: Then you have to process the file to a JSON format that Solr can understand.

Comment: Actually, the latest Solr supports more arbitrary JSON files with instructions of how to map them to Solr better. See [/update/json/documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-TransformingandIndexingcustomJSONdata) handler.

Comment: Ah, good point @AlexandreRafalovitch - you still have to create the mapping somewhere, though. You can't just send arbitrary JSON to Solr and then query on that afterwards.

Comment: @MatsLindh Correct. You still need to know how you want to map it. Though you can always have dynamicField * and map it to Strings. That's effectively what ElasticSearch is doing with its magic mapping.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was: how should the answer look like?

As @AlexandreRafalovitch  wrote, SOLr is designed to return the document, where you search-term exists. Of cause SOLR can search trough the docs or insight the docs using regexp.

But what would be you benefit, if you search for one term, that can be found in your single file an SOLR returns the one an only file as result ?

I had an equal situation where I need to search insight many big documents (1GByte+ per file).
My solution was to split that big document into small ones: ever page as one document.

There was an big benefit: the application was able to point out the page, where the search-term resits.

So in your case, you could split your text-files by lines an process each line as a document. So you can search trough the documents an return the information, if the term exists an on which line.

By the way: you should think about the point, if SOLR isn't a bit oversized for your needs. If there is only one document to search trough, simply loading the file with an regexp interpreter (on system console or your favourite programming language) would be the easiest way.